# How do I read all feed items?

Tags: c#

I want to read all items of a feed in C#. The solutions I've found are only for the latest items like just the last 10 days.

Anybody has a good solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can tie into something like Google Reader, which archives old feed items (although I'm not sure it's a permanent archive or not), then perhaps you can accomplish this.

Comment: Thanks Thomas

I had the idea from google reader. Never thought in tying it. I'll try it. Worst case, I can expand all feeds and get the info in the html.

Answer (score 3):

Libraries for reading feeds typically read all the data in the feed, but feeds typically only contain recent data - you need a source of data that includes older items, not a better library for reading the data you have.

Most entities publish feeds to allow people to track when new content is published, not to make all their data available in a more convenient machine readable format. For this purpose, publishing recent data only makes sense as it saves on bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

Most RSS feeds are only written to deliver a relatively short period of time - 'all' items in a feed generally need you to have created your own archive over time.

Answer (score 0):

Extending thomas' answer, The two google-related archives of feed data you can find are the official one:

Google AJAX Feed API
http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxfeeds/

which will limit you to 250 items, and the unofficial one:

Google Reader API
http://www.niallkennedy.com/blog/2005/12/google-reader-api.html

which will give you unlimited (i think) items but you will need to work around their authentication (something with cookies) and pray they don't change or drop the API (as it is undocumented).

Answer (score 0):

I tried Google Reader, but ther archive was incomplete. I know the people who run the blogs, so I just asked them for a export.

Comment: I don't think Google Reader always archived RSS feeds. I was surprised one day when I went into Google Reader and could read older postings.